# Dispatch call queued. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I'm trying to set a `ScreenName` and send a hit via the Analytics tracker, but I always get the following messages in the LogCat:

```
02-13 23:33:49.311    9700-9700/com.myapp V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Dispatch call queued. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete.
02-13 23:33:49.313    9700-9718/com.myapp V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
02-13 23:33:49.313    9700-9718/com.myapp V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
02-13 23:33:49.313    9700-9718/com.myapp V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: sr=1440x2392,  ht=1423863229311,  cd=MainActivity,  sf=100.0,  _u=.r3K-AL,  cid=667e7eb7-f428-4ece-8b30-c2b24336e595,  av=1.0,  a=947261575,  v=1,  an=myapp,  ul=iw,  t=screenview,  tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-2,  aid=com.myapp,
```

Although it sends the hit to the service, it doesn't dispatch it to the Analytics server so that it will appear in the Real-Time overview...
Here is how I initialize the tracker variable inside the Application class:

```
synchronized Tracker getTracker() {
   if(mTracker == null) {
      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      analytics.enableAutoActivityReports(this);
      analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(3);
      analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
      mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
}
```

app_tracker.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-2</string>
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100</string>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Google Play devices hits will be send over to the device wide Analytics Service without any delay from your application. This service dispatches the events to the Analytics server with some predefined dispatch interval. You can't control the service dispatching interval. Local dispatch period is only used on non-Google Play devices (like Amazon Fire phone). Btw 3 seconds local dispatch interval is quite aggressive (only used on non-Google Play devices). It means that your app will power up the mobile radio practically each time you send a hit. If you only send few hits a day that might not be a big deal. If you are sending hits regularly that might have significant impact on the device battery.